# document ready var unknow

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I use jquery, bootstrap and handlebars.
When i click on a tab, i call some function.
In these function, i use some var.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var sourceLodgerContactAvailable = $("#lodger-contact-available-result-template").html();
        var templateLodgerContactAvailable = Handlebars.compile(sourceLodgerContactAvailable);


        $("a[href='#lodgerContactTab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

            e.target; // newly activated tab
            e.relatedTarget; // previous active tabF

            var location = assignLocationToLocal();
            $.when(location).then(function () {
                getNotAssociateContact();
                getAssociateContact();
            });
        });

    );

    function getNotAssociateContact() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/contacts/notassociatedto/" + $("#lodgerId").val(),
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

                $("#lodgerContactAvailableDivTemplate").empty();

                if (data.length != 0) {
                    $("#lodgerContactAvailableDivTemplate").append(templateLodgerContactAvailable(data)); //error
                    $('#lodgerContactAvailableTableResult').bootstrapTable('resetView');
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                check401Unauthorized(jqXHR);
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

I get this error message.

templateLodgerContactAvailable is not defined

It's like the var in unknow in the function.

Do i need to put the funciton in the document ready?

Comment: Your templateLodgerContactAvailable variable only has local scope within $(document).ready. You'll need to reference it outside of that, if you wish to use it in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the variable from the function

```
$.when(location).then(function () {
            getNotAssociateContact(templateLodgerContactAvailable);
            getAssociateContact();
        });



function getNotAssociateContact(templateLodgerContactAvailable) {
       //your logic goes here

}
```

Or else declare the variable outside the document.ready function

Answer (score 1):

Variables are set to their function scope and any child scopes.

```
function aFunction() {
  var a = 12;
}

function bFunction() {
  // This won't work because `a` is defined in `aFunction`
  console.log(a);
}

var c = 12;

function cFunction() {
  // Works because `c` is declared outside of this function
  console.log(c);
}

function dFunction() {
  // Works for the same reason as `cFunction`
  console.log(c);
}
```

So if you want to use that variable in both places, you should declare it *outside* of `$(document).ready` then assign it's value inside of `$(document).ready`

```
var templateLodgerContactAvailable;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sourceLodgerContactAvailable = $("#lodger-contact-available-result-template").html();
  templateLodgerContactAvailable = Handlebars.compile(sourceLodgerContactAvailable);
  ...
});
```

An even better way would be to have `getNotAssociateContact` take a parameter. Then you can pass that variable to `getNotAssociateContact`.

```
function getNotAssociateContact(template) {
  // Use `template` instead of `templateLodgerContactAvailable` inside of this function
  ...
}
```

Then when you want to call the function, just pass the value to it.

```
var sourceLodgerContactAvailable = $("#lodger-contact-available-result-template").html();
var templateLodgerContactAvailable = Handlebars.compile(sourceLodgerContactAvailable);

$("a[href='#lodgerContactTab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

  e.target; // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget; // previous active tabF

  var location = assignLocationToLocal();
  $.when(location).then(function() {
    getNotAssociateContact(templateLodgerContactAvailable);
    getAssociateContact();
  });
});
```